# How can I get traces in live mode from lttng in my c++ application without using tcp sockets?

Tags: c++, lttng

I'm using lttng api in my c++ application to get traces, but the only solution I found is using tcp sockets. Can I do this without using network?

Comment: It looks like it's required. The [documentation](https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/) says it uses TCP to communicate between various components.

Comment: Yes, [this diagram](https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-plumbing) more specifically. You can see that the LTTng live protocol is over TCP. Also, AFAIK, this protocol is not documented. Your best bet is to look at what [Babeltrace 1 does](https://github.com/efficios/babeltrace/tree/stable-1.5/formats/lttng-live). Note that the upcoming Babeltrace 2 will have a C API to consume LTTng live packets and events (still over TCP connections).

Comment: @eepp Thanks a lot! I was thinking maybe there is an efficient way to get LTTng packets from consumer demon before TCP is used.

Comment: Starting from LTTng 2.11 (still a release candidate as of this date, but the feature works), you can _rotate_ a tracing session, manually or automatically (periodically or based on file sizes). When a rotation occurs, LTTng creates a trace chunk which is not managed anymore by LTTng: therefore you can read/modify/remove it. There's also a C notification API to get notified when a rotation occurs (and what's the created trace chunk's path). There are no repeated event records in contiguous trace chunks.